# Sharing values between methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, return-value

I thougth I knew how to use return in Python but something came up and i dont understand it.

```
    class Projet(object):
       def pathDirectory(self):
           pathDir= str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(ui.pathTab1, 'Select Path','', QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly))
           return pathDir

       def goFunc(self, pathDir):

         # do function
         # HERE pathDir is a boolean and not a str with the path directory

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       p = Projet()
       pathDir = p.pathDirectory()
       p.goFunc(pathDir) ## This is the line where it begins
```

So I have a function that gets a path directory in a variable and return it.
And i want to use the path directory in other functions but when i call it, it's no longer a string but it's a **boolean** (i get a *False* when i print `pathDir`)

UPDATE : sorry guys, typing mistake, it's pathDir and not path, but still returns *False*

Comment: you set `path  = ...` but then return `pathDir`, I dont see pathDir defined

Comment: You are returning `pathDir` in `pathDirectory`. I think you wanted to return `path` there.

Comment: That's why I say - Don't drink and code. You initialized path but return pathDir.

Comment: @AdityaJoshi haha! oops, my mistake (typing mistake) but pathDir is still False when i try to use it in another function

Comment: @AnindyaDutta yes sorry that was a typing mistake but the problem is still here, still returns FAlse

Comment: Hey try this in main function: pathDir = p.pathDirectory(), and next line, print pathDir. What's printed then?

Comment: @AdityaJoshi it prints the correct path directory (when printed in the _name_="_main_")

Comment: @guy16 How and from where are you calling goFunc? Dude we've gotta solve it now. I can't get back to what I was doing...

Comment: @AdityaJoshi goFunc is connected to another function, when i click a button goFunc is executed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79633/discussion-between-aditya-joshi-and-guy16).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Rather than passing variables unnecessarily, you can create a member variable of the class. This variable can be updated and reused by any other function without you having to worry about passing parameters.

```
class Projet(object):

    def pathDirectory(self):
        print "- - in pathDirectory - -"
        self.pathDir= str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(ui.pathTab1, 'Select Path','', QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly))

    def goFunc(self):
        print "- - In goFunc - -"
        print self.pathDir

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Projet()
    p.pathDirectory()
    p.goFunc()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo.

```
   def pathDirectory(self):

       path= str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(ui.pathTab1, 'Select Path','', QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly))

       return pathDir
```

should be:

```
   def pathDirectory(self):

       pathDir = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(ui.pathTab1, 'Select Path','', QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly))

       return pathDir
```

as it is you're setting `path` and then not returning it.

Comment: Yep sorry, my bad, i made a typing mistake, but i still get a False value when i try to use pathDir in another function though

Answer (score 0):

```
def pathDirectory(self):

       path= str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(ui.pathTab1, 'Select Path','', QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly))

       return path #edited
```

You should change the `return` statement to `return path` since `path` is storing the value in the previous line.

Comment: I did, sorry that was a typing mistake, but i still get a False whenever i try to use pathDir in another function